# How to display milliseconds in a countdown timer label?

Tags: swift, countdowntimer

I'm creating a game where you have to tap as much circles as possible for 10 seconds. If the user taps a circle, counter+=0.15 milliseconds, but if he misses it, counter-=0.15

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Now this is the timer function:

```
func updateTimer() {
    counter-=1
    timerLabel.text = "\(counter)"
    if counter == 0 {
        timerLabel.fontColor = UIColor.red
        timerLabel.text = "TIME'S UP"
        resetGameLabel.isHidden = false
        Circle.removeFromParent()
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    if counter < 0 {
        timerLabel.fontColor = UIColor.red
        timerLabel.text = "TIME'S UP"
        resetGameLabel.isHidden = false
        Circle.removeFromParent()
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Now what I want is to display milliseconds on that timerLabel.text, how can I do it?

Comment: FYI,  the timer is not guaranteed to fire in exactly one second,  only when the runloop it is on exceeds the allowable time

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
func currentTimeInMilliSeconds()->Int64 {
    return Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
}

var counterInMilliSeconds = currentTimeInMilliSeconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

If You Create a var timeToDisplay: Double   and make it equals to the time, you  can add or remove the milliseconds you want, and then just make the label Equals to var timeToDisplay instead of your counter.

Comment: what do you mean by add or remove milliseconds? How can I do that? Example?

Comment: Like timetoDisplay -= 0.5 or timetoDisplay += 0.5